# "Failed to connect to the host via ssh" error Ansible

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am trying to run the following playbook on Ansible:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  remote_user: test
  gather_facts: no

  vars_files:
    - files/aws_creds.yml
    - files/info.yml

  tasks:
    - name: Basic provisioning of EC2 instance
      ec2:
        assign_public_ip: no
        aws_access_key: "{{ aws_id }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_key }}"
        region: "{{ aws_region }}"
        image: "{{ standard_ami }}"
        instance_type: "{{ free_instance }}"
        key_name: "{{ ssh_keyname }}"
        count: 3
        state: present
        group_id: "{{ secgroup_id }}"
        wait: no
        #delete_on_termination: yes
        instance_tags:
          Name: Dawny33Template
      register: ec2

    - name: Add new instance to host group
      add_host:
        hostname: "{{ item.public_ip }}"
        groupname: launched
      with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"

## Here lies the SSH code
    - name: Wait for SSH to come up
      wait_for:
        host: "{{ item.public_ip }}"
        port: 22
        delay: 60
        timeout: 320
        state: started
      with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"


- name: Configure instance(s)
  hosts: launched
  become: True
  gather_facts: True
  #roles:
  #  - my_awesome_role
  #  - my_awesome_test

- name: Terminate instances
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Terminate instances that were previously launched
      ec2:
        state: 'absent'
        instance_ids: '{{ ec2.instance_ids }}'
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
fatal: [52.32.183.176]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added '52.32.183.176' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nPermission denied (publickey).\r\n", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [52.34.255.16]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added '52.34.255.16' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nPermission denied (publickey).\r\n", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [52.34.253.51]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added '52.34.253.51' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nPermission denied (publickey).\r\n", "unreachable": true}
```

My ansible.cfg file already has the following:

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking = False
```

Yet, the playbook run is failing. Can someone help me with what I am doing wrong?

Comment: is SSH setup properly? the logs indicate your public key isn't working.

Comment: @andyhky Yeah.  `ssh-add`ing the pem file worked :) . Pl add it as an answer. Will accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer has to lie in:
    Permission denied (publickey).
You got past host key checking - your problem is with authentication.
Are you intending to use key-based authentication? If so, does

```
ssh <host> -l <ansible_user>
```

work for you, or does it produce a password prompt?

Are you trying to use password authentication? If so, it looks like your node does not allow it.

Edit: 
adding `-vvvv` to your playbook enables SSH debugging.

Comment: -vvvv did it for me and turned out the known_hosts file was messed up.

Answer (score 1):

is SSH setup properly? the logs indicate your public key isn't working